# Database connection file isn't working correctly

Tags: php, mysql

The below file works correctly (accepting a JSON string from python and inserting the data.  However, when I break out the database connection information to a separate file nothing is uploaded.  When I call the receiver script in the browser outside of the python script I get "Connection Successful" and an error because no JSON data was passed (which is to be expected).

This works:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "practice";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if( $conn->connect_error ) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    $payload_dump = $_POST['payload'];

    $payload_array = json_decode($payload_dump,true);

    if( is_array( $payload_array ) ){

        $queries=array();

        foreach( $payload_array as $row ){
            //get the data_payload details
            $device = $row['device'];
            $type = $row['data_type'];
            $zone = $row['zone'];
            $sample = $row['sample'];
            $count = $row['count'];
            $time = $row['date_time'];
            $epoch = $row['epoch_stamp'];

            /*note: we do not need to add the semi-colon here as it gets added later when we implode the array */
            $queries[]="INSERT INTO `data` ( `device`, `type`, `zone`, `sample`, `count`, `date_time`, `epoch_stamp` ) VALUES ('$device', '$type', '$zone', '$sample', '$count', '$time', '$epoch')";
        }
        /*
            Previously the below query was being execute on every iteration
            ~ because $epoch is now the last one encountered in the array, 
            the value that is updated in ALL records is as it would have been
            previously.
        */
        $queries[]="UPDATE `data` SET `date_time` = from_unixtime( $epoch ) WHERE date_time = 0;";

        $sql=implode( ';', $queries );
        if ( $conn->multi_query( $sql ) === TRUE ) {
            echo "New records created and updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
    $conn->close();

?>
```

This does not:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
if( $conn->connect_error ) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

?>
```

with this...

```
<?php
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $payload_dump = $_POST['payload'];

    $payload_array = json_decode($payload_dump,true);

    if( is_array( $payload_array ) ){

        $queries=array();

        foreach( $payload_array as $row ){
            //get the data_payload details
            $device = $row['device'];
            $type = $row['data_type'];
            $zone = $row['zone'];
            $sample = $row['sample'];
            $count = $row['count'];
            $time = $row['date_time'];
            $epoch = $row['epoch_stamp'];

            //$queries[]="INSERT INTO `data` ( `device`, `type`, `zone`, `sample`, `count`, `date_time`, `epoch_stamp` ) VALUES ('$device', '$type', '$zone', '$sample', '$count', '$time', '$epoch')";
            $queries[]="INSERT INTO `data_test` ( `device`, `type`, `zone`, `sample`, `count`, `date_time`, `epoch_stamp` ) VALUES ('$device', '$type', '$zone', '$sample', '$count', '$time', '$epoch')";

        }

        //$queries[]="UPDATE `data` SET `date_time` = from_unixtime( $epoch ) WHERE date_time = 0;";
        $queries[]="UPDATE `data_test` SET `date_time` = from_unixtime( $epoch ) WHERE date_time = 0;";

        $sql=implode( ';', $queries );
        if ( $conn->multi_query( $sql ) === TRUE ) {
            echo "New records created and updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
    $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Any error message being reported? What does the query look like that is generated? You should use prepared statements.

Comment: the reason is, you didn't select a database. You should have gotten something from `echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;` and/or your logs. Watch this; some answer's gonna pop up below.

Comment: Plus, if your connection file isn't in the same folder as your executable code, then that also will contribute to its failure.

Comment: If any of these comments are getting through here and solved this question, just send me a sign; as in "delete the question". I'll check back in 10 mins. If it hasn't, you'll need to interact here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Would a Ouija board help at all?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It would. I think crystal balls are slowly going out of style. However... nothing like a good 'ol fashioned Genie, *eh Smokey?*

Comment: Well, those 10 mins. are up. I'll either be damned if I do, or damned if I don't submit an answer for this. *What say ye?*

Comment: Something or other [petronus](http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02097/Potter_2097647b.jpg) @Fred-ii-

Comment: [Smokey's funnier](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/looneytunes/images/8/8a/Somkey.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110829021152)  @RiggsFolly Hardly a "hare" on Harry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing you're probably not getting notifications for comments, maybe an answer will.

As per my comment, you've not selected the database:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

Do as you did in the one that works:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "practice";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if( $conn->connect_error ) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
```

Plus, make sure that connection file is inside the same folder that the code is being executed from.

Comment: If this still doesn't work for you, I will be deleting this answer, no questions asked.

Comment: @ghowe the question should be marked as solved then. People may think the question is still open and might submit other answers.